# How to use Gigabit Ethernet Jacks with integrated magnetics for Fast Ethernet only

Tags: ethernet, wiring, magnetics

If have a Fast Ethernet PHY (LAN8720 for example) and want to use an Gigabit type of Ethernet Jack with integrated magnetics (RJMG201GMU1208R for example). Is it even possible/allowed and what would be the correct wiring for that?

Can I just leave the remaining pairs unconnected?

Comment: You can leave the 2 extra pairs unconnected, or better yet, check some reference designs, they can be terminated. If you intend on using PoE in the future, you should take that into account. 1000BaseT connectors are usually more expensive than 100BaseT.

Comment: The RJMG201GMU1208R cannot support PoE so that's taken care of. If passive PoE is applied, it will get damaged, but so do many 100M magjacks too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, as long as the transformer coupling is otherwise compatible. The LAN8720 requires 1:1 CT and the RJMG201GMU1208R provides 1:1 CT. Just use the same pairs you would use for any 100M Ethernet magjack. The unused pairs can be left unconnected like they would be on a 100M connection.